# Using Spring to connect to a database that dynamically changes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, h2, jooq

I have seen many solutions which all make you first configure statically via XML the different datasources and then use AbstractRoutingDataSource to return back a key which you consume while defining the datasource.

As here: [dynamic datasource routing](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

But my case is different. I dont know how many databases there could be in my web application. I am building an app where each user uploads a small h2 db dump from a desktop app. The web app will download the h2 db dump and then connect to it.

So to make things simple to understand. Each user will have his/her own database file that I need to connect to once the user logs in. Since the number of users are not fixed, I dont know how many databases I will need to connect to, hence I cannot statically configure them in an XML file.

How to go about doing this in Spring? Also, not sure if it helps, these h2 dbs are read only. I am not going to write to them.

This is my configuration.

Maven, Spring MVC, JOOQ, H2 DBs

Comment: Since the client will initiate the connection, let them pass what's needed to connect.  The read only character is immaterial.

Comment: I can do that. I know how to get the connection when the user logs in. I was wondering how to make use of Spring injection for this though.

Comment: Would a session scoped bean that abstracts the connection creation and h2 file download be the right approach?

Comment: you could programatically create the datasource and anything else needed (entity Manager factory) on the fly

Comment: I am not sure this is an appropriate use of spring.  However take a look at method injection: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-method-injection

Comment: I landed up doing this - I created a session scoped bean that acts like a factory for the connection. The factory downloads the h2 dump and then gets a connection to it and dishes it out to whoever needs it. I injected this factory into all my daos.

Answer (score -1):

If you like to change the database changes dynamically, you have to write the UI for database source information and set to the spring config files in version-4.0.